# MyMonero Import fee - payment from import?

Tags: mymonero

I know that there is a fee to use MyMonero to import monero to a mymonero wallet.

My question is this - is the fee deducted from the imported monero, before it is lodged in the mymonero wallet, or do i need to pay with monero before the import occurs - so effectively I need to have monero to pay the import cost before it allows the import?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fee for importing moneros. It's a fee for importing your address's transaction history. A wallet cannot import moneros because moneros are not stored in wallets. They're stored at addresses on the blockchain.

Your address could have a history associated with it, if someone has previously sent moneros *to* it, or if you you have previously used some other wallet software to spend moneros *from* it. If you pay the fee, MyMonero will trawl through a copy of the blockchain (kept on a mymonero.com server) and figure out your transaction history.